# C# BinaryFormatter.deserialize to object for sending over sockets

Tags: c#, sockets, binaryformatter

I have a client that serializes a class to a stream, which goes through a socket, to my server.
So i send this object to my server, where my server would save the ''object'' by doing:

```
object readObject = formatter.Deserialize(stream);
```

It fails to deserialize saying:
Unable to find assembly etc. etc.

Does this mean there is no way for my server to take the object, push it through a few more sockets to other clients, where the clients deserialize it? Does the server really require the original class in order to deserialize to an object?

I do not want my server to be able to open all these objects at all, i just want it to serve was a broadcaster to all my active clients.

Help is appreciated, 
Smiley

Comment: "Does the server really require the original class in order to deserialize to an object?" Um, yes. What type of object do you think it will create otherwise?

Comment: I thought an object was just an anonymous storage of sorts. as in, it can be ANY object, until you choose to cast it to something. But apparently that is not going to happen then?

Comment: No, an object is absolutely *not* just anonymous storage. Put it this way - what would you expect to happen if you called `GetType()` on the result of your deserialization?

Comment: I would expect it to know the type/name of the object inside, but not be able to cast it to that type, because it doesn't know how it is build up.

Comment: If you don't need the server to actually treat the data as objects, why not just keep it as the raw binary data and serve that back to the clients?

Comment: If i knew how i could properly do that, i would love to, since that is all it needs to do. but i have no clue as to how properly read the stream to do this, and not mess up. (since i will be sending various sizes of objects, and multiple in a row over the same socket)

Comment: You should prefix each message with its length, basically. So it's (length, data), (length, data) etc.

Comment: hmm ill google that seperate then. i was hoping to avoid that method though. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have the source code to the client and server, you could extract the class definition for the object into a separate class library project (DLL) and then reference it from both the client application and the server application.  That way, both of them have knowledge of the class and deserialization should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

For example code look at TCPMessageServer available open source from codeplex

https://tcpmessageserver.codeplex.com/